# what books are best for django 3?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-3.0

what books are best for django 3?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: This is probably not the right type of question for Stack Overflow because there is no non-opinion answer and the question is too broad. [in my opinion]. Personally, I like Two Scoops of Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, the best you can do is to read the whole documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ it answers most of the questions you might have and it shows what is possible to do with Django. Its very well written and I really enjoyed reading it. You should be able to write your Django app by yourself after reading the doc, and google only the specific problems you will encounter while developing using Django framework.